# Unable to search a query with symbols in elasticsearch

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have been trying to match a query using the *elasticsearch* *python client* but I am unable to match it even after using escape characters and setting up some custom analyzers and mapping them. I want to search using `&` and its not giving any response.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])


doc1 = {
    'name': 'numb',
    'band': 'linkin_park',
    'year': '2006'
}

doc2 = {
    'name': 'Powerless &',
    'band': 'linkin_park',
    'year': '2006'
}
doc3 = {
    'name': 'Crawling !',
    'band': 'linkin_park',
    'year': '2006'
    }

doc =[doc1, doc2, doc3]
'''
create_index = {
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

es.indices.create(index="idx_temp", body=create_index)
'''
for i in range(3):
    es.index(index="idx_temp", doc_type='_doc', id=i, body=doc[i])


my_mapping = {
  "properties": {
      "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  'ignore_above': 256
              }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "band": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
              }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      },
      "year": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
              }
          },
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
  }
}

es.indices.put_mapping(index='idx_temp', body=my_mapping, doc_type='_doc', include_type_name=True)

res = es.search(index='idx_temp', body={
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "powerless &",
                "fuzziness": 3

            }
        }
    }
})

for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    print(hit['_source'])
```

The expected output was `'name': 'Poweeerless &',` but i got 0 hits and no value returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have fixed the problem by adding another field

```
 "search_quote_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
```

to the settings field after

```
"analyzer": "my_analyzer"
"search_analyzer": "my_analyzer"
```

And then I'm getting my output by searching with `&` in the query as

```
'name': 'Poweeerless &'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it using your index settings, mapping, and query and was able to get the results. Below are 2 different things which I did.

1. Escape the special char `&`, when I was trying to index the doc using ES REST API directly, using below the body in postman:

> {
>       "content": "Powerless \&" }

**Then ES gave me the `Unrecognized character escape '&'` exception and even Postman, popular REST client was also giving me warning about not a proper string.**

Then I changed above payload to below and was able to index the doc:

```
{
    "content": "Powerless \\&" :-> Notice I added a another `\` to escape the `&`
}
```

2. I changed the query to use the same field, **which was having the value `&`, in your case it is `name` field, not the `content` field.**, As match query is [analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and uses the same analyzer which is used for indexing time. And was able to get the result.

PS: I also verified your analyzer using [_analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) api and it's generating the below tokens for text `Powerless \\&`

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "powerless",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "\\&",
            "start_offset": 10,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So basically what I have to do is to **search** the symbol **&**  and therefore have to map my analyzer to the index, I have made some changes in the code and now I'm gettting an error :




```

elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'analyzer on field [name] must be set when search_analyzer is set')
```

Can you help me fix my problem and map my custom analyzer to be mapped on the index and den search for an query which contains symbols.

Comment: Can you show me your mapping and what changes you did ?

Comment: I have fixed the problem by adding ```"search_quote_analyzer": "my_analyzer"``` to the settings field and now my problem is fixed, but I got another issue that I'm getting a lot of useless results when used on a large dataset, so is there any filtering feature so that the result I recieve have score which are maximum and no useless suggestions.